# Use Django Static File in React Component

Tags: python, django, reactjs

Below I have a very basic example of my react structure in my Django app. How would I reference a static file within a React Component? I'm attempting to make a header in react, and wondering if its possible to display image from within Component.

Logo.jsx

```
import React from "react"

export default class Logo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <a href="{% url 'index:landing_index' %}"><img src="{% static "img/logo.png" %}"></a>
    )
  }
}
```

NavBarContainer.jsx

```
import React from "react"
import Logo from "../components/Logo"

export default class NavBarContainer extends React.Component {

  render() {
      return (
          <Logo />
      )   
   } 
}
```

NavBar.jsx

```
import React from "react"
import { render } from "react-dom"

import NavBarContainer from "./containers/NavBarContainer"

class NavBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavBarContainer />
    )
  }
}

render(<NavBar />, document.getElementById('navbar'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to manually add the static path or send the path through via a java script tag variable.

```
<script>
var static_root = {{ STATIC_URL }}
</script>
```

Comment: React will still complain about not being able to find STATIC_URL when it compiles

Comment: I have done this in the past when using Redux, it is indeed possible this way!